# How Can I Flip an Axis WITHOUT Visually Flipping a Chart

Tags: excel, charts, axis-labels, excel-2016, excel-charts

I have a chart in Excel which looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that with my data, 100 is the lowest possible rating whilst 1 is a much higher score. As such I want the chart to have 0 at the top of the vertical axis and 100 at the very bottom.

Normally I'd reverse the vertical axis but this causes a boatload of problems visually and things which I didn't specifically ask Excel to do:

[image]

1.) the bars are all going down which visually looks negative if I wanted to show success. I need the bars to go up not down!

2.) Since 100 is the lowest score, the 'filling' (visual formatting of the bars) should stretch from 100 to the designated value, not from 0 to the designated value as current which is completely wrong

3.) basically the transparent parts of each bar (column) should be filled and the filled parts of each bar (column) should be transparent so visually it needs a complete inversion in terms of bar colour filling

This is what I want the chart to look like in-case I confused the heck out of you:

[image]

If you compare the first and third images from this post (the top and bottom images, not the one in the middle) you will see they are the same except for the axis order and bar inversion which I had to create manually in MS paint!

How can this be achieved? Pulling my hair out, have been looking for literally hours to just get this one chart right and (sadly) I really can't do it on my own. Any help would be **GREATLY** appreciated!

I am using Windows 10 64 bit with MS Office / Excel Pro Plus 64 bit 2016

Answer (score 1):

You could play with the data set to represent it differently i.e. use stacked column chart

Assuming this is your original table of data

[image]

Just add a complementary value (out of 100) row into the original data
[image]

Then insert chart as usual - stacked column
reverse the axis, then fill transparent as invisible

Set label position to high.
You'll get something like below:[image]

Don't worry about the legend, just hide it.

Comment: Thanks! That's not actually a half-bad way to do it, though unfortunately assumes the source data can be edited and is not generated (external sources, pivot tables etc) so will fall down in those scenarios. Still it's better than nothing. Because this isn't quite perfect I won't mark it as the answer but I will upvote it

Comment: How did you use values in reverse order without it flipping the horizontal axis up to the top?

Comment: After setting it to reverse, Format axis > Labels > Label Position - set High from dropdown

Answer (score 1):

So easy,
Just do your chart normally, then R-Click the values Axis & select (Format Axis).
From Axis Options pull down @ Horizontal axis crosses tick the (Maximum Axis Value) Radio button.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much I found this really helpful